# Why does this FilterParameter not work as expected?

Tags: asp.net, filter, sqldatasource

I have a gridview with columns: `id`, `name`, `address`, `phone`
And a TextBox: `NameFilter`

My gridview is populated by a SqlDataSource controller.

I need to filter my gridview registers with `name`.

I'm trying with 'FilterParameters' but I don't know why this does not work.

**NameFilter**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NameFilter" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

**SqlDataSource**

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="NameFilter" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:okadConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:okadConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM factory">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I believe that the `<br/>` inside your filter not exist, and you add them here for better format. Please remove them and add 2 spaces. And what is your `Select command` ?

Comment: Oh, Sorry! I had take "<br/>" for broke line in StakeOverflow. My SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM factory"

Comment: If this is the select, you do not have include there your parametre, thats why is not work .

Comment: Please, can you show me how to make this select with parameters?

Comment: One more, do you have include the `FilterExpression=`  ? on your SqlDataSource ? Here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterparameters.aspx

Comment: Thenk you very much!!! It is work now! Yes, I had not set FilterExpression, I thought just need set FilterParameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `FilterParameters` you just create the SQL parameters, but to make them usable you need to include also the `FilterExpression`.

for example you also need to add:
`FilterExpression="name='{0}'"`

reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterparameters.aspx

Alternative you can add `<SelectParameters>` as

```
<SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="NameFilter" Name="name"
          PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

and use : `SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM factory WHERE name=@name"`

Comment: I'm tried your alternative option, but when "NameFilter" is empty, it return zero registers, Have any resolution?  And I need filter data when I click a ImageButton

Comment: I updated my question, I post complete code of my SqlDataSource. How to add filter with C#? Because I need active this filter when click a ImageButton